# Is it possible to create this kind of custom view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

[image]

I was just wondering if I can create a similar kind of layout in android.

The custom view must be expandable depending upon image nature. I tried with `GridView` to make this kind of view.

If anyone has worked with a similar kind of thing let me know. Thank's in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by image nature? please specify??

Comment: image with no specific size,If image is a portrait then view should be expanded

Comment: as ebarrenchea mention staggeredGridview should do the trick additionally you can try QuiltView https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at `StaggeredGridView` [here](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) as it does something similar, although not exactly what you are looking for. You can find a demo project [here](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo) if you want to have a quick look at how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through gridview.
You will have to create a ViewGroup and will have to inflate the views on scroll.
And when you add any view to the viewgroup that view will contain the image, title,etc. 
And the main pot is that you will have to set the width of that view equal to 1/4 of the width of the ViewGroup, and the width of the image in that view equals to match_parent and height of the view and image both should be wrap_content.

Try it once using ViewGroup and inflater, And you will find your way.
Hope that helps.